# IntelliJ Community Edition 2016 Scala Worksheet shows strange output instead of literal value

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, intellij-16

I've used the scala worksheet in InteliJ and have run across a problem where the right-hand side (REPL-like output) shows what appears to be a namespace or memory address instead of the useful-to-a-human literal value.

In the scala REPL (not IntelliJ) the following is quite sane

```
scala> val nums = new Array[Int](10)
nums: Array[Int] = Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

However, in the Scala worksheet the same yields a not-so-useful output

```
nums: Array[Int] = [I@1a2a52bf
```

After some light googling and reading I tried the following

```
val nums = new Array[Int](10)
nums
nums.toString()
nums.mkString(", ")
```

Which output

```
nums: Array[Int] = [I@1a2a52bf
res0: Array[Int] = [I@1a2a52bf
res1: String = [I@1a2a52bf
res2: String = 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
```

There's got to be a simple solution or explanation for this that I'm missing. Has anyone run across this and fixed it before?

Here's a worksheet screenshot for reference:

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ionmn.png)

Comment: the output is correct for me in Intellij 2016.1.4. Intellij worksheet always some inconsistencies with scala REPL, especially when you use some libraries like cats/shapeless, or try some cases relevant to scopes.

Comment: but i guess you'd better check your intellij scalac version, which should be more important in your case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IntelliJ's worksheet uses `toString` to print variable. `Array[Int]` in Scala corresponds to Java's `int[]` which doesn't override `Object`'s `toString` method.

Here is `Object`'s `toString` method:

```
public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```

Scala's REPL on the other hand has special logic for certain classes, `Array` among them.

There is nothing to "fix", it's just how these tools are designed. If you want to pretty print Array's value in Idea's worksheet, use `java.util.Arrays.toString`  or convert value to another collection:

```
val a = Array(1,2,3)
a.toString
java.util.Arrays.toString(a)
a.toSeq
```

Produces:

```
a: Array[Int] = [I@4df3d702
res0: String = [I@4df3d702
res1: String = [1, 2, 3]
res2: Seq[Int] = WrappedArray(1, 2, 3)
```